# Not able to make POST request from zuul Microservice to another microservice

Tags: rest, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am routing all requests from zuul-micoservices to datasource microservices where in all the API methods live.

i am making a call from zuul-MS to datasource-MS POST operation,i am not able achieve it but all the GET operations are working which involves no pathvariable parameter.

github: https://github.com/javayp/ms

Answer (score 1):

It might be issue with connection timeout - I had very same problem and it helped adding following settings (using zuul with eureka):

application.yml:

```
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 60000
  ConnectTimeout: 20000
```

(solution found here: [spring-cloud-zuul timeout configuration does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525707/spring-cloud-zuul-timeout-configuration-does-not-work))