# spring-cloud-zuul timeout configuration does not work

Tags: spring, netflix-zuul

according to spring cloud zuul [8.1.3 zuul timeout](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html), the following configuration should make zuul timeout after 20 seconds, however, it times out at 10 seconds.

```
server:
  port: 8769
spring:
  application:
    name: service-zuul
zuul:
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 20000
    socket-timeout-millis: 60000
zuul:
  routes:
    tp:
      path: /**
      url: http://localhost:9998
ribbon:eureka:enabled: false
```

[image: stack trace]
From console output one can see that the interval between filter and timeout exception is only 10 seconds. which means the `zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis` does not work.

Comment: The output also shows that a java...socketexception exception caused it, doesn't it?.

Comment: @rjv I guess that means `zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis` does not work?

Comment: Not sure that only a test can tell. I asked a question and I got a question instead of an answer ! :) I wanted to check with you if the socketexception could have caused the timeout ie., what code caused the zuul host to timeout ?

Comment: @rjv yes, `SocketTimeoutException: read timed out` is the base exception. There was no code caused the error, I think the backend server takes longer time than 10 seconds to handle the requests.

Comment: There are so many unknowns so let me make a few guesses. 1., why the wildcard usage Do you want all /** to be routed to the home service? 2., Is the home service correct? 3. Do you have a proxy? If I am making sense for you till this point then 4., Can you provide a FallbackProvider for a Route in which you can create a fallbackResponse or response of type ClientHttpResponse to return the cause of an exception?

Comment: The usage scenario is quite simple, everything related to route is configured in yml. The wild card means everything sent to GW is redirected to a backend server with uri remained but host changed. GW is used as a zuul proxy, no `FallbackProvider`. the fallback response is done by a `/error`.

Comment: "When a circuit for a given route in Zuul is tripped, you can provide a fallback response by creating a bean of type FallbackProvider." This is from the same link provided by you. So, I suggest you write the fallbackProvider bean class so that the fallbackResponse can tell you the cause of the exception. Hope this helps.

Comment: @rjv I m looking for solutions to modify zuul timeout time. Not to how to handle when a timeout exception happens.

Comment: Ok, since there is a gray *ribbon:* entry in your screenshot that says eureka is disabled, add the readTimeout: <value> and connectTimeout:<value>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

I used properties before and this is the first time to try yml, it seems that an item must be aggregated into one prefix:

```
zuul:
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 20000
    socket-timeout-millis: 60000
  routes:
    tp:
      path: /**
      url: http://localhost:9998
```

In this way the backend server could have at most 60 seconds to respond. Besides, I also found that the sequence in configuration matters.

Answer (score 2):

Try to define the below properties instead if you are using Zuul withe Eureka.

```
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 60000
  ConnectTimeout: 20000
```

If you are using Zuul with Eureka, Zuul will use `RibbonRoutingFilter` for routing instead of `SimpleHostRoutingFilter`. In this case, HTTP requests are handled by Ribbon.

Comment: That's true, but I was not using zuul with eureka.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below config to Zuul gateway to make it work:

hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled= true

ribbon.ReadTimeout=5000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=5000

#(ribbon.ReadTimeout + ribbon.connectTimeout) * (1+ribbon.maxAutoRetries(default 0) * (ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer (default 1) + 1)
#timeoutInMilliseconds= (5000 + 5000) * (1+0)*(1+1) =20000

hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=21000

Note: Though the IDEs complain this is unknown property, it still works.